# Joining two tables where id does not equal

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm struggling getting this query to produce the results I want.

I have:

table1, columns=empid, alt_id

table2, columns=empid, alt_id

I want to get the empid, and alt_id from table 1 where the alt_id does not match the alt_id in table2. They will both have alt_id numbers I just want to get the ones that do not match.

Any ideas?

Comment: What prevents you from doing this?  Or to put it another way, what are you confused about?

Comment: Please add sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM table1
INNER JOIN table2 ON table2.empid = table1.empid AND table2.alt_id <> table1.alt_id
```

Answer (score 0):

What does that really mean though? Normally when this is asked, it is of the form "I want all rows from A that have no row matching in B and all in B that have no match in A"

Which looks like this:

```
SELECT * FROM
  A
  FULL OUTER JOIN
  B
  ON
    a.id = b.id
```

You'll see a null for any row data where there isn't a matching row on the other side:

```
A.id
1
2

B.id
1
3

Result of full outer join:

A.id B.id
1    1
2    null
null 3
```

You, however have asked for A-B join where the IDs aren't equal, which would be the more useless query of:

```
SELECT * FROM
  A
  INNER JOIN
  B
  ON
    a.id != b.id
```

And it would look like:

```
A.id B.id
1    3
2    1
2    3
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to want `not exists`:

```
select t1.*
from table1 t1
where not exists (select 1 from table2 t2 where t2.alt_id = t1.alt_id);
```

It is unclear whether or not you also want to join on `empid`, so you might really want:

```
select t1.*
from table1 t1
where not exists (select 1 from table2 t2 where t2.alt_id = t1.alt_id and t2.empid = t1.empid);
```

Answer (score 0):

A left join will find all records in `Table A` that do not match those in `Table B`.  Then use a `Where` filter to find the Nulls from `Table B`.  That will give you all those in `Table A` that do not have a matching ID in `Table B`.

```
    Select A.*
    from Table A
    Left Join
    Table B
    on a.altid = b.altid
    where b.altid is null;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select * 
from [Login] L inner join Employee E 
on l.EmployeeID = e.EmployeeID 
where l.EmployeeID not in (select EmployeeID from Employee)
```